# Angular 2 Binding Issue on Child Routes

Tags: javascript, angular, binding, alpha

I have a small starter project to learn the basics of Angular2 but have a simple issue where I'm sure I must be missing something obvious.

I am using JSPM, ng2 alpha 37, js files in es6 and babel transpile. There is an app container component and 3 other skeleton components which I can successfully route to and see the appropriate html.

On the introduction of a simple string property in anyone of the three components I cannot seem to bind the value in the view, however trying the same code on the parent container component the same structure of code works.

Child Component Example

```
import { Component, View } from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({ 
    selector: 'self-employed-calculator' 
})
@View({
    templateUrl: 'app/components/self-employed-calculator/self-employed-calculator.html'
})
export class SelfEmployedCalculatorComponent {
    constructor() {
        this.test = 'Boom';
        console.log(this.test);
    }
}

<section class="mui-panel">
    <p>Self-Employed Calculator</p>
    <h3>{{ test }}</h3>
</section>
```

Console log reports the correct value but the rendered html is

```
<h3 class="ng-binding"> </h3>
```

Using the same approach on the parent component I get the result I expect

```
import { Component, View } from 'angular2/angular2';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig } from 'angular2/router';
import { HomeComponent } from 'app/components/home/home';
import { BudgetPlannerComponent } from 'app/components/budget-planner/budget-planner';
import { SelfEmployedCalculatorComponent } from 'app/components/self-employed-calculator/self-employed-calculator';

@Component({
    selector: 'playground-app'
})
@View({
    templateUrl: 'app/components/playground-app/playground-app.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', redirectTo: '/home' },
  { path: '/home', as: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: '/budget-planner', as: 'budget-planner', component: BudgetPlannerComponent },
    { path: '/self-employed-calculator', as: 'self-employed-calculator', component: SelfEmployedCalculatorComponent }

])
export class PlaygroundAppComponent {
    constructor() {
        this.title = 'test';
    }
}

<header class="mui-appbar mui-z1" style="margin-bottom:20px">
    <div class="mui-container mui-appbar-line-height">
        <span>
            <a [router-link]="['/home']" class="mui-text-title mui-text-white">Angular 2 Playground</a>
        </span>
        <nav class="mui-text-white mui-pull-right">
            <div class="mui-dropdown">
                <button class="mui-btn" data-mui-color="accent" data-mui-toggle="dropdown">
                    Components
                    <span class="mui-caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="mui-dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a [router-link]="['/self-employed-calculator']">Self-Employed Calculator</a></li>
                    <li><a [router-link]="['/budget-planner']">Budget Planner</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<main class="mui-container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
    <footer>
        &copy; My Footer
    </footer>
</main>
```

I see the expected result

```
<h3 class="ng-binding">test</h3>
```

[Git Source](https://github.com/StepChangeCharity/angular2-playground/tree/ca14b3d305a054b265ff70df181d1fa08eca3741)

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a plnkr? I don't want to sound rude, but installing VS2015 just to try this is a little bit too much. Besides that, in your  `playground-app.html` file you are using `router-outlet` and `router-link` which requires you to inject them through `directives` (`RouterOutlet` and `RouterLink`, don't forget to import them from `angular2/router`).

Comment: You don't actually need VS2015 to run this.  Just navigate to "src\angular2-playground" npm install (which then triggers jspm install) and then npm start should do it. The routing injection is already in which is injected into the main app component view with "ROUTER_DIRECTIVES" and works already. Cheers

Comment: Meanwhile I see what it could be, I just want to rectify my last comment : `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` includes both `RouterLink` and `RouterOutlet`. Sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks for looking much appreciated, been driving me mad!

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I couldn't find what's going on. I got interested in this question because I had a similar one a few time ago (see my [question](https://gitter.im/angular/angular?at=55f0264c760979e727e94553) and the [answer](https://gitter.im/angular/angular?at=55f045d7532e5edc65554e3d)). Your configuration looks too big and probably the issue is in it. You could try to go with a simpler set up as [ng2-play](https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/ng2-play.ts). IMHO JSPM looks too complicated.

Comment: Well it seems it was potentially with the way my dependencies were being imported or js being compiled. I have re-created on  plunker using pretty much the same code at it works! http://plnkr.co/edit/SQSvdRuIE5Ef58Do0O7I?p=preview

Comment: Just a little update : see [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4288), just adding zone.js apparently solves this problem.

Comment: @EricMartinez thanks for this, would mark it as the answer if I could. Have just got around to trying and this indeed solves the problem by installing zone.js through jspm and adding "import 'zone.js';" to my bootstrap file.